# Why we must copy one set before calling the appropriate bulk operation?

Tags: java

why I have to write the first statement before calling bulk operation??

```
Set<Type> union = new HashSet<Type>(s1);
union.addAll(s2);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One must instantiate an object before calling a method.

In this case, trying to call the `addAll` method on a `null` object will cause a `NullPointerException`. Therefore, the `Set` `union` object must first be constructed somehow, then can it used in any meaningful way.

---

I think it would be a good idea to go over the given code and try to understand what the code is trying to accomplish.

```
Set<Type> union = new HashSet<Type>(s1);
union.addAll(s2);
```

The above code is tells me the following:

1. Let's make a new `HashSet` from the existing elements of the `Collection` `s1` (which I assume to be something like another `Set`.)
2. The newly created `HashSet` will be stored as a `Set` with the name `union` -- the code seems to imply that this new `Set` is going to represent some kind of union.
3. To the `union`, elements from another `Collection` (probably another `Set` that is called `s2`) will be added by the `addAll` method.
4. Now, I think that the `union` object contains an union of the `Set`s `s1` and `s2`.

When writing code, one should pay attention to trying to tell others what the code intends to do. Having the code explain what it's doing is going to result in more readable and maintainable code that is going to make it easier (and possibly a pleasure) for others to read and understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can ensure a more optimal union if you declare the capacity of your union set to be the combined sizes of s1 and s2.

```
HashSet<Type> union = new HashSet<Type>(s1.size() + s2.size());
union.addAll( s1 );
union.addAll( s2 );
```

Furthermore, you can put this union code into a static method of another utility class so all your calling code is only one line

```
public abstract class Unionizer {
    public static final HashSet<Type> union( HashSet<Type> s1, HashSet<Type> s2 ) {
        HashSet<Type> union = new HashSet<Type>(s1.size() + s2.size());
        union.addAll( s1 );
        union.addAll( s2 );
        return union;
    }
}
```

Now everywhere you need to union two sets together you only need to type:

```
HashSet<Type> union = Unionizer.union( s1, s2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't need to copy another set, but you need to call the new operator. You could have:

```
Set<Type> union = new HashSet<Type>();
union.addAll(s2);
//and if you want s1 to be included too:
union.addAll(s1);
```

Comment: you believe or you are sure??/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this more elegantly, use the [double brace initialization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DoubleBraceInitialization):

```
Set<Type> union = new HashSet<Type>() {{
   addAll(s1);
   addAll(s2);
}};
```

Comment: Why don't you put the first set in as construcotr argument?

Comment: That's not elegant - it's a horrible abuse IMO.